# How to un escape strings extracted from json objects in java?

Tags: java, json, escaping, decode

In my java program where I download a json object, when I get a string from it, it will be like `"what\'s"` for example, even though in PHP I put in `"what's"`. It has back slashes to escape the quotes and possibly other characters. Is there a java function I can use to unescape this and turn it into `"what's"`?

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
firstname = object.getString("firstname");
```

Comment: How do you "get a string from it"? Most Java JSON libraries take care of unescaping strings.

Comment: I added the code to show how I get the string.

Comment: It looks like there's some double escaping going on somewhere in the data pipeline.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean to remove the back slashes, use `String.replace()` method to replace all `\` to empty substring.

I think its like this

```
String s = yourString.replace("\\","");
```

Comment: I could do string replace, but then how do I handle for all types of escaped characters, there would be many replacing... I am looking for some function maybe built in that will convert it for me, I dont want to re invent the wheel here.

Comment: There could be an issue with escape sequences like newline `\n`

Comment: Em, sorry i cant comment so this not an answer, use replaceAll(regex, replacement) method the first argument is regex, give the regex, i don know regex to give u

Comment: it turns out that when I make http requests in java and if my string has a quote, then when php reads it, it will somehow be escaped there and will have a blackslash, so I would need to unescape it in php code.

Comment: If your `string = "some\' string\'s"`,  `string.replace("\\","")` gives this output : `some' string's`,

Comment: I know, but the solution is to use the `stripcslashes` php function when getting the string from the `$_POST[]`.

Comment: This will not take care of unescaped special characters where é is converted to \u00e9.